# Using PPL with an operator new override

Tags: visual-c++, ppl

I have a large (million line) VC++ project, and would like to start using PPL (Parallel Patterns Library) within the project. The project implements a custom global operator new and operator delete functions. The problem is that PPL (in a debug build) uses its own

void* operator new[](size_t cb, int nBlockUse, const char* szFileName, int nLine)

but then when it de-allocates, my operator delete(void*) gets called, and since the memory layout is totally different, this doesn't work.

My question is whether there is a way to use PPL in a debug build without abandoning my global new and delete operators. There are good reasons for having these global new & delete overrides, removing them from my project is not an option at this time.

Answer (score 1):

This was a bug in PPL in Visual C++ 2010; it was fixed in Visual C++ 2012.

You may be able to work around this by writing your own replacement debug operators new and delete that call your own custom operators new and delete:

```
void __cdecl operator delete(
    void*       block,
    int const   block_use,
    char const* file_name,
    int const   line_number
    )
{
    return operator delete(block);
}

void __cdecl operator delete[](
    void*       block,
    int const   block_use,
    char const* file_name,
    int const   line_number
    )
{
    return operator delete[](block);
}

void* __cdecl operator new(
    size_t const size,
    int const    block_use,
    char const*  file_name,
    int const    line_number
    )
{
    return operator new(size);
}

void* __cdecl operator new[](
    size_t const size,
    int const    block_use,
    char const*  file_name,
    int const    line_number
    )
{
    return operator new[](size);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned I'm using VS2013.

When I try to override 

void* __cdecl operator new[](
    size_t const size,
    int const    block_use,
    char const*  file_name,
    int const    line_number
    )


the linker reports


LIBCMTD.lib(dbgnew.obj) : error LNK2005: "void * __cdecl operator new[](unsigned __int64,int,char const *,int)" (??_U@YAPEAX_KHPEBDH@Z) already defined in UDMemory.obj

The /FORCE:MULTIPLE linker option does not solve the problem either.